# How to check for a symbol that requires two header files in CMake?

Tags: header, cmake, symbols

To get symbol getifaddrs defined you have to include both sys/types.h and ifaddrs.h. When checking whether the symbol exists, I've tried the following:

```
set (CMAKE_EXTRA_INCLUDE_FILES sys/types.h)
check_symbol_exists (getifaddrs ifaddrs.h SP_HAVE_IFADDRS)
set (CMAKE_EXTRA_INCLUDE_FILES)
```

However, the test program still includes only ifaddrs.h and thus fails to detect the symbol.

How can I force it to include sys/types.h as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

check_symbol_exists (getifaddrs "sys/types.h;ifaddrs.h" SP_HAVE_IFADDRS)